# jQuery - Date control- Whats wrong with the below code?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm a beginner in jQuery.

The below code is from my aspx code behind

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH1">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () 
  { //debugger
  $("#<%=datepicker.UniqueID %>").Datepicker();;
  });
</script>    
 <div> Date: <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

I didn't get any response upon clicking the text box.

Can anyone point out the issue in the above code.

Is there any site that demonstrates the **jquery controls by integrating with asp.net** code ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me if the extraneous semi-colon after DatePicker() would cause issues?  Just curious...

Comment: A good site for integrating jQuery with .NET (especially using AJAX) is Dave Ward's site, http://encosia.com

Comment: GregL is the url right ?

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker() method must be written with a lower-case "d".

Comment: Thanks Cito.  I did tried by changing the case. still not working

Comment: I'm not an ASP.net expert, but maybe you need to replace `UniqueID` with `ClientID`? Have a look at the generated HTML and check whether the ID of your input element and the ID specified in your jQuery code match.

Comment: Thanks Cito.  It did the magic.  Below is the code              $(function()
    {
     $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").click(function()
     {
//     alert('');
          $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker();
     })                                                           But this time i got a different error 'object doesnt support  this property or method'

Comment: Are you sure jQuery UI is loaded properly and includes the datepicker widget (again, check the generated HTML and the jquery-ui.js file)?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger click event on textbox and assign the callback of this click on document ready. Try in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#myID').click(function()
     {
          $(this).datepicker();
     })
});
```

**UPDATE**

If is not necessary you can write html code instead of asp tag.

```
<input type="text" id="myID"/>
```

If asp tag is necessary, for example you want use OnServerClick consider that javascript onClick event will always trigger first.

As @Cito said DatePicker constructor method must be written in lower case.

Comment: Thanks Matteo Vinci. the code below works                $(function()
    {
     $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").click(function()
     {
//     alert('');
          $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker();
     }) But this time i got a different error 'object doesnt support  this property or method